# AWS Cognito - AdminInitiateAuth vs InitiateAuth

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We're looking to leverage AWS Cognito for authentication with an architecture that looks like:
`client (browser) -> our server -> AWS Cognito`

With various configurations set, `initiateAuth` seems no different to `AdminInitiateAuth` and so I'd like to understand when under these configurations if it matters whether one is chosen over the other.

It seems that when I create an app with a `client secret` and use `initiateAuth`, it seems to be almost the same integration experience as `adminInitiateAuth` that uses the `ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH` auth flow. The latter does not even require AWS credentials as stated in the AWS documentation. My integration with Cognito is as below:

**initiateAuth**:

```
  const payload = {
    AuthFlow: "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
    ClientId: cognitoClientId,
    AuthParameters: {
      USERNAME: username,
      PASSWORD: password,
      SECRET_HASH: generateSignature(username)
    }
  }
  const response = await cognitoClient.initiateAuth(payload).promise();
```

**adminInitiateAuth**:

```
  const payload = { 
    UserPoolId: userPoolId,
    AuthFlow: "ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH",
    ClientId: cognitoClientId,
    AuthParameters: {
      USERNAME: username,
      PASSWORD: password,
      SECRET_HASH: generateSignature(username)
    }
  }
  const response = await cognitoClient.adminInitiateAuth(payload).promise();
```

You can see the difference is the different `AuthFlow` values, calling different methods and `ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH` requiring the `UserPoolId` parameter which seems superficial to me.

We are also generating the signature based on the client secret which is something that we would handle securely.

Comment: Also posted on [AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=295226)

Answer (score 26):

I understand that you would like to know the difference between the `InitiateAuth` and the `AdminInitiateAuth` API calls in Amazon Cognito. 
To clarify the usage of the API calls:

- `InitiateAuth` is a client/browser side API call, and the API call does not need any sensitive credentials to give a challenge and other parameters.
- `AdminInitiateAuth` is a meant to be run in the server side, and the API call **always** needs developer credentials to give a successful response. This is because the API call is an AWS SigV4 signed API call.

Furthermore, both the API calls support different Auth Flows as specified below.

`InitiateAuth` supports the following Auth Flows:

- USER_SRP_AUTH
- REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH
- USER_PASSWORD_AUTH
- CUSTOM_AUTH

Kindly note that the AWS CLI documentation [a] currently states that ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH is a possible value. However, I have tested the API call on my end and I can confirm that the documentation for the CLI is *currently* incorrect.

UPDATE (12/09/2019): It looks like after this answer was written, Amazon Web Services has updated their documentation to the correct possible values. The documentation now states the following:

```
ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH is not a valid value.
```

`AdminInitiateAuth` supports the following Auth flows:

- USER_SRP_AUTH
- REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH
- CUSTOM_AUTH
- ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH
- USER_PASSWORD_AUTH

Example use-case of `InitiateAuth`: If you want your users to authenticate into your web application.

Example use-case of `AdminInitiateAuth`: Any use-case that needs server side authentication or access based on specific AWS Credentials to filter that only specific IAM users can authenticate using Cognito.

As stated by [george](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3793865/george) earlier, `InitiateAuth` would be ideal for your use-case as your application is a client side application.
Additionally, if you are concerned about security, you could use the USER_SRP_AUTH with `InitiateAuth`. For more information about using the USER_SRP_AUTH flow in your production code, you could refer to the following NPM documentation[b].

## References

[a]. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/initiate-auth.html

[b]. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cognito-srp

Comment: Thanks for the response @lightyagami. I've edited my original question to ask the crux of what I'm actually looking for rather than starting it off as a general question.

Answer (score 9):

initiateAuth and adminInitiateAuth do a similar thing, however, they have different use cases and flow.

initiateAuth is used when you have **an end user client app.** The user enters their creds and they are sent via Secure Remote Password Protocol. If the flow succeeds the end user gets a token back and is allowed access. This flow is used by the Android, IOS and Javascript SDKs because it's to do with the client side.

adminInitiateAuth is used when you don't have a client end user app but a secure back-end app using Java, Python or some other backend language. This method **does not** accept username-and-password user credentials for admin sign-in but requires AWS credentials.

In your case, if you had a client app ---> Cognito and use for example Android SDK or Javascript SDK directly then you should use initiateAuth from within the SDK passing the user credentials. However, browser -->back-end--> Cognito meaning you have a dedicated back-end so in your case you should adminInitiateAuth. More info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-custom-authentication-flow)

Comment: Thanks for the response @george. I think what you've answered is the typical use case but hasn't answered my specific question. Using `initiateAuth` with a user pool that has a client secret seems no different to `adminInitiateAuth` with `ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH`. The latter does not require AWS credentials and both require a secret hash to be calculated using the client secret.

Comment: I've re-worded my question. Perhaps it started off too general when I was looking for a difference in the specific configurations

Answer (score 5):

AdminInitiateAuth only exists for one reason: so you can avoid the hassle of SRP in your server side code while still requiring client side code to use SRP.

SRP is more secure, but annoying/inconvenient to implement. Also, if you're writing code that runs on the server, a lot of the benefits that SRP provides are irrelevant anyway (your code is running in a secure, protected environment).

If you set up a Cognito app client like this:

```
[X] ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH
[ ] ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH
[X] ALLOW_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH
```

... then any untrusted/public client side code must use SRP, but trusted server side code is free to use the plain old user/password flow. (Of course the server side code has to have AWS credentials in order to enjoy this privilege)

You're absolutely spot on though that the two are pretty much equivalent in functionality with some superficial differences.

Answer (score 3):

I too spent quite some time researching scarce documentation on the topic of 
when to use AdminInitiateAuth vs InitiateAuth.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html is supposed to help, but I find it poorly structured and very confusing.

From my understanding, you're right, you can use both approaches on the server:

1. `InitiateAuth` with `AuthFlow=USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` (requires app client to be created with client secret).
2. `AdminInitiateAuth` with `AuthFlow=ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` (replaced legacy `ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH`)

I believe second option makes more sense for the server usage scenario though. This way you can disable `ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` auth flow in the app client settings altogether. While probably not a huge risk, it feels cleaner to not have `InitiateAuth` API open to the public since it's not required.