# AWS Cognito InitiateAuth with/without Access Key and Secret Access Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I need to authenticate with AWS Cognito using InitiateAuth https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-cognito-idp-2016-04-18.html#initiateauth which is on AWS account with "X"(example id) AWS Account id.

Do i need to have "AWS Access Key" and "AWS Secret Access Key" on that same "X" AWS Account in order to Authenticate with Cognito or it is possible to Authenticate with AWS Cognito without those.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't exactly clear what you mean by authenticate with AWS Cognito, but Cognito Identity Pools allows you to assign authenticated users a set of temporary, limited privilege credentials to access AWS resources in an account. The documentation is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html).

The idea is that you create an Identity Pool for your users to authenticate. You also create the appropriate IAM roles that grant the required permissions. When your users authenticate they assume these roles and receive temporary credentials to access the resources.

Comment: I need to call InitiateAuth to get the refresh token. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-cognito-idp-2016-04-18.html#initiateauth.  Cognito is not on my AWS Account, do i need AWS Access Key and Secret Access Key from the AWS Account where Cognito is on in order to do this?

Comment: I updated my question with more details @kgiannakakis

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53755308/aws-cognito-admininitiateauth-vs-initiateauth may help you.